# Create jQuery Promise for File API readAsText

Tags: jquery, html, fileapi, deferred, promise

I am using a file input element with which a user will select a single text file:

```
<input type="file" id="myfile">
```

I would like to create a jQuery Promise associated with the asynchronous event of the FileReader object loading the selected file's content. I tried code like this in various contexts but there appears to be some type of timing issue as I don't get the contents variable passed to the then() callback:

```
var promise = $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
  var file = $("#myfile")[0].files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload =  function(event){
    var contents = event.target.result;
    dfd.resolve(contents);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}).promise();

// other code and promises here

$.when(promise).then(function(contents){
  console.log(contents);
});
```

There are in fact two events involved. The first event occurs when the user clicks the Browse button and selects a particular file. A second event is when the FileReader is loaded with the selected files contents. If anyone know how to get this packaged correctly so I will have a promise that when resolved holds the contents of the selected file I would appreciate your insight. Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't `console.log(data)` be `console.log(contents)`?

Comment: is `promise1` in the second piece of code supposed to be `promise` from the first bit?

Comment: Your code looks fine other than the mentioned typos.

Comment: Those were typos I created I simplified my code for posting here. I think to demonstrate the problem I am having I will have to create a complete html page. I think the problem I am experiencing has to do which where and when I am creating the promise in relation to the form elements. I will revise the question with a precise example of the problem. Thanks for now.